# BigQuery Audit Logs - Difference between JobInsertion and JobChange

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

In the BigQuery logs (Audit MetaData) we have two entries that look very similar:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata

[image]

What's the difference between JobInsertion and JobChange? They're practically the same apart from   JobChange having a property `after: "DONE"` and JobInsertion has `reason: "QUERY_REQUEST"`

When querying those logs, do we only need to look at one of them?

Answer (score 0):

In Google BigQuery Audit Logs, both **JobInsertion** and **JobChange** entries represent actions related to BigQuery jobs, but they serve slightly different purposes.

`JobInsertion` indicates the **creation or insertion of a BigQuery job**, typically when a query request is made to the BigQuery service. The reason field, in this case, specifies why the job was inserted, which is usually [QUERY_REQUEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata.JobInsertion.Reason) for regular query requests.

`JobChange` represents a **change in the status or metadata of a BigQuery job**. The after field indicates the state of the job after the change, which could be any other [status](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata.JobState) such as DONE, RUNNING, PENDING, etc.

Comment: Is it possible then to have multiple JobChange entries for the same query? I don't think I've seen any with running/pending